# Asp.NET Controls Validation using jQuery 1.10.2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to validate `asp.net` controls using `jQuery`. I want to show validation in Asp.NET `Label` if `TextBox` is empty and after all validation, if it satisfies condition then allow `Button` to fire its backend Code.
I am using jQuery 1.10.2.min in my whole Project which after Body Part in `Master Page`. So do I need to put in `Head` Part ???
**My Code :**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblNote" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Create an account" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
```

**Head :**

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=txtFirstName.UniqueID %>:{
                        required:true
                    },      
                    <%=txtEmail.UniqueID %>: {              
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }
                }, messages: {
                    <%=txtFirstName.UniqueID %>:{
                        required: "* Required Field *"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It is showing me error : `TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function`

Comment: Did you try any Jquery? show us.

Comment: Yes, but it is refreshing page on button click.

Comment: Put you Jquery code and I'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use asp.net built in RequiredFieldValidator.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="Required field"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Create an account" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
```